# Getting vscode c++ plugin to locate protocol buffer headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, bazel

I am using bazel to build a c++ application that includes protocol buffers. This means that bazel runs the protocol buffer compiler as part of the build process, and squirrels the generated files away somewhere within the bazel output directory. VSCode is then unable to resolve these #include directives since they are not on any include path that vscode knows about.

But I'd rather not hardcode some frequently-changing bazel output directory in my vscode config. Does anyone have any suggested strategy for resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode `<bazel_workspace_path>\bazel-genfiles` or `<bazel_workspace_path>\bazel-bin` as include directories.

`bazel-bin` and `bazel-genfiles` are junctions (~= directory symlinks) that point to the corresponding output directories. (They are called convenience symlinks. See the [`--symlink_prefix` flag](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html) for more info.)

Comment: What if we installed it with gRPC which installs protobufs like here https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/#setup? Where is protobuf header filels located